# Missing Edit Privileges Option In PhpMyAdmin

Tags: mariadb, phpmyadmin, xampp

The Action column of the PhpMyAdmin is not displaying the Edit Privileges. I did not get the solution for this problem. I even tried to upgrade and degrade the PhpMyAdmin version, but nothing worked. I have attached a screenshot of PhpMyAdmin for verification. Please verify it and give me the solution to this problem.

Operating System: Windows 10,
Php Version : 7.2.34, [image]
Message : You do not the privileges to administrate the users!

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if the user you are logged in as does not have the privileges needed to edit access. The edit links are only shown if your user is able to modify permissions.